# How do I set up my Sprint Samsung Galaxy Note 5 as a hotspot for free?

Tags: wi-fi, samsung, wifi-tethering

I've tried downloading several apps from the app store but they do one of two things; they either hang and don't work, or they bring up the phone's hotspot screen and ask me to pay for the service.

I am trying to avoid paying for an additional metered data plan from Sprint. I already pay them $125 a month for just this one phone and service.

There's a guy who has a video on youtube on how to do it, but you have to pay him for the info and I fear I'll have to root the phone.

I'd prefer not to root the phone.

I'd like to be able to share the 4G LTE Internet connection with my laptop. My laptop is a Samsung NP900 ultrabook.

I have an unrooted 64GB, Galaxy Note 5 on the Sprint system in the United States:

Android version: 5.1.1
Model number: SM-920P
Software Version: N920PVPU2AOJ6
Hardware Version N920PO3 
Kernel: 3.10.61-5944578

Hope this is enough information. Please let me know if you need more. Thx

Comment: Found something that can help without rooting the device. link:http://forum.xda-developers.com/sprint-galaxy-note5/general/native-hotspot-stock-rooted-rooted-t3188703

Comment: I think that you need to contact sprint to check if you can get a compatible data plan.

Comment: I rolled it back because changing the title completely changed the question hence the last comment by @reachrk . I know how to enable sprint hotspot. They charge an arm and a leg and limit the bandwidth. You pay for a separate data plan. I know there are ways to set up a hotspot without buying an additional data plan. A guy has a way to do it on youtube but he charges and doesn't tell you in advance. I'm sure he's just rooting the phone. I don't want to root a phone I just spent almost a 1000 dollars for. I have the 64 version.

Comment: @Iakovl Thank you. I am going to try it. I have to get the MSL but I think you're on to something. If I figure it out I'll post the answer here. Thx